# idn2.h: No such file or directory

Tags: centos, rpm, yum, idn

I am on 64-bit Centos 6.6 and want to install libidn2-devel. I tried `yum install libidn2-devel` and that didn't work. I tried downloading rpms from various websites from Internet(resolving recursive dependencies manually!)

(Not so) Soon I stuck at the one of the dependencies

```
libidn2.so.0()(64bit) is needed by libidn2-devel-0.10-1.sdl7.x86_64
```

which I could not find anywhere on the Internet (for CentOS).

Eventually, I downloaded the [source](https://gitlab.com/libidn/libidn2) and tried to build it.

```
wget -c ftp://alpha.gnu.org/gnu/libidn/libidn2-0.10.tar.gz
tar -xvzf libidn2-0.10.tar.gz
./configure
make
```

Success!

However, when I used it to run a module, it gives me

```
error: idn2.h: No such file or directory
<idn2_variable> was not declared in this scope
```

---

PS : RPM seems weird

```
$ rpm -q libidn2-devel
package libidn2-devel is not installed
$ rpm -q libidn2
libidn2-2.0.4-1.el6.x86_64
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`libidn2-devel` is provided via the [EPEL Repo](https://download.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/6/x86_64/)

```
Name        : libidn2-devel
Arch        : x86_64
Version     : 2.0.4
Release     : 1.el6
Size        : 54 k
Repo        : epel
Summary     : Development files for libidn2
URL         : https://www.gnu.org/software/libidn/#libidn2
License     : (GPLv2+ or LGPLv3+) and GPLv3+
Description : The libidn2-devel package contains libraries and header files for
            : developing applications that use libidn2.
```

The wiki page [here](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/EPEL) will give you some more details, and if you want to install EPEL for use with `yum` then you should download (and install) [this](https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/epel-release-latest-6.noarch.rpm) `rpm` to your system then check in `/etc/yum.repos.d/epel.repo` for the config file it will leave. Inside there you need to check the `[EPEL]` section has the line `enabled=1` (I think its disabled by default)

You may want/need to clean up the stuff you have tried to manually install though so you avoid any problems with updates etc.