# Yum repository - unable to find correct one

Tags: linux, amazon-ec2, yum

Just wondering if someone can help me find a yum repository or repositories that will allow me to download the following dependencies?
I am trying to install these items on a standard Amazon linux box
libopencv-dev 
python-opencv
libfreetype6-dev
libgl1-mesa-dev

Thanks
Damien

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presuming you are using a CentOS/RHEL build then you can use the standard repos;

All of you missing dependencies are provided by the `base` repo.

```
Available Packages
Name        : opencv-python
Arch        : x86_64
Version     : 2.0.0
Release     : 12.el6
Size        : 843 k
Repo        : base
Summary     : Python bindings for apps which use OpenCV
URL         : http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/
License     : BSD
Description : This package contains Python bindings for the OpenCV library.

Name        : opencv-devel
Arch        : x86_64
Version     : 2.0.0
Release     : 12.el6
Size        : 179 k
Repo        : base
Summary     : Development files for using the OpenCV library
URL         : http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/
License     : BSD
Description : This package contains the OpenCV C/C++ library and header files, as well as
            : documentation. It should be installed if you want to develop programs that
            : will use the OpenCV library. You should consider installing opencv-devel-docs
            : package.


Name        : opencv
Arch        : x86_64
Version     : 2.0.0
Release     : 12.el6
Size        : 4.6 M
Repo        : base
Summary     : Collection of algorithms for computer vision
URL         : http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/
License     : BSD
Description : OpenCV means IntelÂ® Open Source Computer Vision Library. It is a collection of
            : C functions and a few C++ classes that implement some popular Image Processing
            : and Computer Vision algorithms.
```

Have a look in; `/etc/yum.repos.d/` and see if you have a config file with the name `CentOS-Base.repo` if you have open it with an editor and check the required lines have `enabled=1`

I have all of the default & additional repos installed but I don't get matches for any of these packages:

```
libopencv-dev
python-opencv
libfreetype6-dev
libgl1-mesa-dev
```

If you need to download the base repo config then visit [this link](http://vault.centos.org/), pick the correct version and copy the `CentOS-Base.repo` file to the path given above. If you need additional repos (Such as EPEL) then see [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46453597/3788685) to a question I answered for another user.

Comment: Thank you this worked a treat. Have a few more issues at the minute when I run the ldd command on my library - /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.20' not found and libicui18n.so.54 => not found

Comment: any ideas on any of those?

Comment: can you post the output of `rpm -q glibc` - from a very quick check of a CentOS 6.9 box I appear to have `glibc-2.12-1.209.el6_9.2.x86_64`

Comment: after running rpm -q qlibc - I get the following output glibc-2.17-196.172.amzn1.x86_64
glibc-2.17-196.172.amzn1.i686

Comment: Can you jump into chat?

Comment: Cant right now sorry..is it ok if i message you later?

Comment: Sorry had internet issues over the weekend. Please let me know when you are free to chat

Comment: @Damien im online if you still need a quick chat

Comment: hi @user3788685 I think I am good now. Moved over to using ubuntu on AWS and all libs I need are available. Just started a bounty and will  award it tomorrow. Thank you for your patience and guidance on this

Comment: Ahh no problem - glad you got it sorted & thank you :) - The best/easiest things is *always* try and install from a constant source (package, or source) its never good to mix & match unless you know what your doing.

Answer (score 1):

Well, considering Amazon Linux is based on RHEL (RedHat Enterprise Linux) distro it's possible to enable the EPEL (Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux, maintained by Fedora distro guys) repository that contains these packages you want with slightly different names. I'm going to quote AWS help page:

> Amazon Linux – The EPEL repo is already installed on Amazon Linux, but
>   it must be enabled by updating the epel.repo file. The following
>   command illustrates use of the vim editor to update the epel.repo
>   file. vim /etc/yum.repos.d/epel.repo
>
> ```
> a. Locate and change the entry enabled=0 to enabled=1 that is located in the $basearch section of the epel.repo file.
> b. Save and exit the vim editor.
> ```

Now, pay attention that the package names you want follow conventions from other distros, so on RHEL/EPEL repositories might be different. Because of that, try:

```
# yum install mesa-libGL-devel freetype-devel opencv-devel opencv-python
```

Comment: Thanks for those steps - mesa-libGL-devel freetype-devel  installed but not opencv-devl or opencv-python

Answer (score 1):

You need to install the `opencv` pakage from sources, see [How to install OpenCV on Amazon Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34244606/how-to-install-opencv-on-amazon-linux)